# Hover a div with NgClass

Tags: html, css, angular, ng-class

I am trying to make a hover effect on a div with a Angular ngClass directive. In the template file I have a div element with class "list-item-container' which contains a div with class "list-item" that is iterated with a *ngFor directive. Inside the "list-item" div element I have three divs with class "list-item-column" which are placed horizontally like a table row with inline display. in the div with "list-item" class I have placed a mouseenter and mouseleave event listeners which calls hoverListItem() in my .ts file.  the hoverListItem() function changes the value of listItemHovered variable to true or false. In the "list-item" class I have a ngClass directive which triggers a css class 'list-item-highlight' based on the value of listItemHovered boolean value which then changes to background to a different color.

The problem I'm facing is that upon hovering mouse pointer on the "list-item" div all my "list-item" divs are affected instead of the one I am hovering over. How to solve this problem?

.html file

```
<div class="list-item-container">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let opportunity of dealService.opportunities">
        <div [ngClass]="{'list-item-highlight': listItemHovered}" class="list-item" (mouseenter)="hoverListItem()"
             (mouseleave)="hoverListItem()"
             (click)="selectOpportunity(opportunity)">
          <div
            class="list-item-column">{{opportunity.account?.name === null ? "N/A" : opportunity.account.name}}</div>
          <div class="list-item-column">{{opportunity.requirementTitle}}</div>
          <div class="list-item-column">{{opportunity.salesValue | number: '1.0-2'}}</div>
        </div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
```

.css file

```
.list-item-container{
  overflow: auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 500px;
}
.list-item{
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px ;
  margin-top: 5px;
  height: 50px;
  background: lightgray;
  color: black;
}

.list-item-highlight{
  background: #7e00cc;
  color: white;
}

.list-item-column{
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: center;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 33.33%;
  padding-left: 40px;
}
```

.ts file

```
 hoverListItem() {
    this.listItemHovered = !this.listItemHovered;
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now you're creating and modifying `listItemHovered` flag inside component context, rather you should maintain a flag for each item level, which could help to easily identify wheather component has been highlighted or not.

```
[ngClass]="{'list-item-highlight': opportunity.listItemHovered}"
(mouseenter)="hoverListItem(opportunity)"
(mouseleave)="hoverListItem(opportunity)"
```

**Component**

```
hoverListItem(opportunity) {
   opportunity.listItemHovered = !opportunity.listItemHovered;
}
```

---

Though I'd recommend to use `:hover` pseudo class if requirement is just to highlight the element on hover. That can be easily doable by changing CSS rule. This way could save several change detection cycle to be ran.

```
.list-item:hover {
  background: #7e00cc;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: sorry in the .ts file i get an error "property listItemHovered" does not exists on type Deal" (the type of opportunity is Deal).

Additionally, I have tried .list-iitem: hover before. problem is it only applies to the children divs (list-item-column). Only the child div item i hover on gets highlighted instead of the entire row/list-item div

Comment: @Econ_newbie for sufficing typescript, add `listItemHovered` property in `Deal` interface

Comment: @Econ_newbie for `:hover` I don't see any problem should happen to `:hover`

Comment: now the :hover is working. I don't know why it wasn't working before. Maybe there was some problem with my code.  Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest use a `directive` to listen to the hover event on the target element and attach the class:

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[hoverDir]'
})


 export class HoverOverDirective { 
    @HostListener('mouseenter') onMouseEnter() {
       this.elementRef.nativeElement.class = 'list-item-highlight';
    }

     @HostListener('mouseleave') onMouseLeave() {
       this.elementRef.nativeElement.class = 'list-item-not-highlight';
     }
}
```

Or the easiest way is to make use of [CSS pseudo property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp)   `:hover` and use it as below:

```
.list-item:hover {
  background: #7e00cc;
  color: white;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Thankfully :hover is working now. I don't know why it wasn't working before. Maybe there was some problem with my code.